# Netbeans warning messages for int[] and int[][] differ

Tags: java, netbeans

I know this is quite a trivial question but why does Netbeans decide to give different "warnings" depending on whether I use `int[]` or `int[][]`

```
int[] oneDArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // The array is only written to, never read from

int[][] twoDArray = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}; // Variable twoDArray is not used
```

Eclipse gives both as "*The value of the local variable  is not used*"

IntelliJ gives both as "*Variable  is never used*"

Comment: This is opinion-based. No one besides the netbeans developers can tell you why they decided to do that.

Comment: Maybe related: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=244841, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Michael It may not be opinion based but I see your point. I thought someone might have seen it before and there was a reason.

Comment: The more general case seems to be that you get _"The array is only written to, never read from"_ if: [1] The variable is a one-dimensional array of any type, AND [2] It is initialized to any value, including null. Otherwise you get _"Variable is not used"_. Also, unused member variables get no warning at all; this only applies to local variables. But as Michael said, I don't think we can know why local one dimensional initialized arrays are a special case unless the NetBeans developer(s) read your question.